Query Records Within Salesforce Flow
I was wondering if anyone happens to have a resource or know a way to query existing records in Salesforce through Salesforce Flow?
Essentially, I have Web2Case enabled with the company case field on the Web2Case form. I want to query if the company name equals any account names within my org or if the Web2Case phone, email, or full name equals matches any accounts or contacts within my org. If so, link that account and contact to the relevant case; if not, create a contact and account with the details from the Web2Case form.
I've been having trouble creating a custom way to query existing accounts in my Salesforce org. So far, I tried to do two loops in Flow: one for contacts and one for accounts, checking if the current item's name, email, etc., match within the case object. However, this didn't seem to work. I now have an APEX invocable method to do the query, This seems to be working, but it's not really the method I want to use since I got the code from ChatGPT + I'm not a developer, so I'm not sure about the maintenance of that method. I wanted to check if there was a simpler way to accomplish this.
I noticed in the Summer ‘24 release notes that the Create element has received some major enhancements in Summer '24, namely the ability to match existing records (and avoid creating a duplicate record) and automatic mapping of required fields. However, I need a more immediate solution until this is generally available.
Here is the code:
public with sharing class CaseHandler {
    public class CaseResult {
        @InvocableVariable
        public Id caseId;
        
        @InvocableVariable
        public Boolean accountExists;
        
        @InvocableVariable
        public Id accountId;
        
        @InvocableVariable
        public Boolean contactExists;
        
        @InvocableVariable
        public Id contactId;
    }

    @InvocableMethod(label='Link Account and Contact' description='Links Account and Contact to the Case based on supplied information')
    public static List<CaseResult> linkAccountAndContactInvocable(List<Id> caseIds) {
        List<Case> cases = [SELECT Id, SuppliedCompany, SuppliedEmail, SuppliedPhone, AccountId, ContactId FROM Case WHERE Id IN :caseIds];
        linkAccountAndContact(cases);

        List<CaseResult> results = new List<CaseResult>();
        for (Case caseInstance : cases) {
            CaseResult result = new CaseResult();
            result.caseId = caseInstance.Id;
            result.accountExists = (caseInstance.AccountId != null);
            result.accountId = caseInstance.AccountId;
            result.contactExists = (caseInstance.ContactId != null);
            result.contactId = caseInstance.ContactId;
            results.add(result);
        }

        update cases; // Ensure the cases are updated after linking
        return results;
    }

    public static void linkAccountAndContact(List<Case> cases) {
        try {
            Set<String> suppliedCompanies = new Set<String>();
            Set<String> suppliedEmails = new Set<String>();
            Set<String> suppliedPhones = new Set<String>();

            // Collect supplied company names, contact emails, and phones from cases
            for (Case caseInstance : cases) {
                if (caseInstance.SuppliedCompany != null) {
                    suppliedCompanies.add(caseInstance.SuppliedCompany);
                }
                if (caseInstance.SuppliedEmail != null) {
                    suppliedEmails.add(caseInstance.SuppliedEmail);
                }
                if (caseInstance.SuppliedPhone != null) {
                    suppliedPhones.add(caseInstance.SuppliedPhone);
                }
            }

            // Query existing accounts based on name and phone
            Map<String, Account> existingAccountsByName = new Map<String, Account>();
            Map<String, Account> existingAccountsByPhone = new Map<String, Account>();
            if (!suppliedCompanies.isEmpty()) {
                for (Account acct : [
                    SELECT Id, Name, Phone 
                    FROM Account 
                    WHERE Name IN :suppliedCompanies
                ]) {
                    existingAccountsByName.put(acct.Name, acct);
                }
            }
            if (!suppliedPhones.isEmpty()) {
                for (Account acct : [
                    SELECT Id, Name, Phone 
                    FROM Account 
                    WHERE Phone IN :suppliedPhones
                ]) {
                    existingAccountsByPhone.put(acct.Phone, acct);
                }
            }

            // Query existing contacts based on email and phone
            Map<String, Contact> existingContactsByEmail = new Map<String, Contact>();
            Map<String, Contact> existingContactsByPhone = new Map<String, Contact>();
            if (!suppliedEmails.isEmpty()) {
                for (Contact contact : [
                    SELECT Id, Email, Phone, AccountId 
                    FROM Contact 
                    WHERE Email IN :suppliedEmails
                ]) {
                    existingContactsByEmail.put(contact.Email, contact);
                }
            }
            if (!suppliedPhones.isEmpty()) {
                for (Contact contact : [
                    SELECT Id, Email, Phone, AccountId 
                    FROM Contact 
                    WHERE Phone IN :suppliedPhones
                ]) {
                    existingContactsByPhone.put(contact.Phone, contact);
                }
            }

            // Update the cases with found Account and Contact IDs
            for (Case caseInstance : cases) {
                // Check if the account already exists by name or phone
                if (caseInstance.SuppliedCompany != null && existingAccountsByName.containsKey(caseInstance.SuppliedCompany)) {
                    caseInstance.AccountId = existingAccountsByName.get(caseInstance.SuppliedCompany).Id;
                } else if (caseInstance.SuppliedPhone != null && existingAccountsByPhone.containsKey(caseInstance.SuppliedPhone)) {
                    caseInstance.AccountId = existingAccountsByPhone.get(caseInstance.SuppliedPhone).Id;
                }

                // Check if the contact already exists by email or phone
                if (caseInstance.SuppliedEmail != null && existingContactsByEmail.containsKey(caseInstance.SuppliedEmail)) {
                    caseInstance.ContactId = existingContactsByEmail.get(caseInstance.SuppliedEmail).Id;
                } else if (caseInstance.SuppliedPhone != null && existingContactsByPhone.containsKey(caseInstance.SuppliedPhone)) {
                    caseInstance.ContactId = existingContactsByPhone.get(caseInstance.SuppliedPhone).Id;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Log the exception
            System.debug('An error occurred: ' + e.getMessage());
            // Optionally, add additional error handling here
        }
    }
}


Have you tried using Get Records?
